# How can I open a `content://` URI that I have permissions for?

Tags: android, kotlin

Say the user gives me access to the `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/1234-5678:Android/media/Music` URI, theoretically, I should then be able to open a file within that URI using an `applicationContext.contentResolver` right?

I tried to get permissions for a given URI using this code

```kotlin
documentTreeOpener = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree()) {
    it?.let { root ->
        requireContext().contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
            root, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

        Log.v("SettingsFragment", "${root.toString()}")
    }
}
documentTreeOpener.launch(null)
```

Say the URI I get permissions for is `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/1234-5678:Android/media/Music`. If I get another URI like `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/1234-5678:Android/media/Music/Artist/Album/song.flac`, I should be able to open it using `applicationContext.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")` right? I'd love to know what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: On your first question the answer is no.

Comment: You should be able to get a file descriptor for the last uri if you have a read permission for it. Without needing any other uri or permission. Confusing post.

Comment: You dont need permission for a directory if you have already a permission to read a file.